# QT: building WinExtras

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.6

I'm trying to compile a static build of QT 5.6.1 from source on Windows.

To do this, I'm issuing the following commands:

Configuration command:

```
configure.bat -static -static-runtime -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl -opensource -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Build command:

```
mingw32-make
```

Now, this seems to compile the toolkit correctly, but at the end there's something missing. In particular, the `winextras` module, which is needed for my process, does not get built. I have the `macextras` and `androidextras` folders in my build directory, but no `winextras` one.

How do I configure properly so that the `winextras` module gets built?

Comment: Is that module included in the sources?

Comment: @KubaOber: I seems to be, theres a "qtwinextras" folder inside the Src folder, and all the source files seem to be there. What shoudl I check for in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was my error. I was missing the Python binary in my PATH, so the build process didn't complete fully, which I hadn't noticed due to the ridiculously low "history" the default windows cmd prompt has, and it looked like it had finished while in reality it had failed.

Comment: `mingw32-make || echo "FAILED"` :)